# Error in fisher.test() : FEXACT error 40. Out of workspace

Tags: r, statistics

Error in fisher.test() : FEXACT error 40. Out of workspace.

I have a two columns data with 16173 observation. When I performed fisher.test in R, it always shows error that it is out of space no matter how large I adjusted the workspace. My question is: Can fisher test handle sample size like this? Can I use chi Squared test as an alternative choice?

Part of the data is shown below:

```
    A   B
[1,]    0   0
[2,]    0.02873563  0
[3,]    0   0
[4,]    0.10185185  0.10666667
[5,]    0.05714286  0
[6,]    0.25925926  0
[7,]    0.02727273  0
[8,]    0.125   0
[9,]    0   0.04
[10,]   0.14876033  0
[11,]   0.61344538  0.2
[12,]   0.24852071  0.01234568
[13,]   0.20491803  0.03703704
[14,]   0.20472441  0
[15,]   0.09375 0
[16,]   0.29661017  0
[17,]   0.15254237  0.07228916
[18,]   0.03278689  0
[19,]   0.04891304  0
[20,]   0.58378378  0.05194805
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Fisher's exact test you examine the significance of the association between two kinds of categories. It's a test that analyses *categorical* data; your sample data is not categorical. What hypothesis do you want to test? Do you perhaps want to compare the population means based on values in both columns (in a t-test)?

Comment: I would to know if it is significant between two samples (let say treatment (A) vs. control (B)) with over 16,000 observations. Is fisher test not suitable in this case?

Comment: Fisher / chi-square test is used for categorical variables, you appear to have numerical values, which cannot be used with these tests. Take a look at t-tests.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. See the help:

> In the r x c case with r > 2 or c > 2, internal tables can get too large for the exact test in which case an error is signalled. Apart from increasing workspace sufficiently, which then may lead to very long running times, using simulate.p.value = TRUE may then often be sufficient and hence advisable.

Indeed, adding `simulate.p.value = TRUE` helps. I didn't try to increase the workspace memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

<s>Fisher test can only be used for very small samples since it's very computationally intensive. You should use a chi-square test.</s>

**Edit:** I wasn't paying too much attention so I made a couple of mistakes. The data appears to be numerical which means Fisher / Chi-square tests are inappropriate, as these tests can only be used with categorical variables. A t-test may be more appropriate.

Also, it's true that the Fisher test can be used for large samples too, the computational limitations are based on table size (number of categories), and is also valid for large samples too. Although for large enough samples the Chi-square test will approximate these results well enough (provided the cell counts are met).

Comment: *Fisher test can only be used for very small samples* That's really not correct. (1) Statistically, there is no reason why you shouldn't use Fisher's exact test for large sample sizes. The "converse" is much more true (and important): A chi-square test is not valid for small sample sizes. But that doesn't mean that Fisher's exact test can't be used for large sample sizes. (2) For sample sizes that OP reports Fisher's test will also not be slow. Try for yourself:  `set.seed(2018); mat <- matrix(as.integer(10^runif(4, min = 4, max = 6)), ncol = 2, nrow = 2); fisher.test(mat)`.

Comment: *Fisher test can only be used for very small samples* -- perhaps you mean small tables ie 2x2 . It does become a computational  issue for larger tables. *A chi-square test is not valid for small sample sizes.*  I believe the usual rule-of-thumb is based on the expected cell count not sample size.

Comment: I believe historically it was used only for small datasets because it's relatively computationally intensive, however, computing power caught up years ago and can be used on large datasets.